# Changing HTML with media queries?

Tags: html, css

I'm building my first website, using right now mainly HTML and CSS.
In order to adjust my website for big screens (desktop computers) as well for tablets and phones, I'm using **media queries** to link my HTML pages to different style sheets.
for example:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop_css.css" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="phone_css.css" media="(max-width: 1200px)">
</head>
```

That works really fine, but I need to change my HTML code as well.
I want to add different images for every "media query", so that for under 1200px width of screen one image will appear, and another for screens with over 1200px width.

How do I do that?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is have all images within the *HTML* content and then in each *CSS* file you could just use `display: none;` to switch image visibility depending on screen-width.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Smoggs/6sf7hz7r/)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
   #img1 {
      display: none;
   }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
   #img2 {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="img1" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0Dav0HDgMJbLCtT-V5EtyNf76ZO5O8SSx_f3Xs-hM_hNvYL6vwnvJ9g" />
  <img id="img2" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmp65xRN2P3FI_nzAj06DyQ_qIsYF3SIvZfdIRFkTlR7EF734x" />
</div>
```

So in your case with external CSS files you would put the MediaQuery containing `#img1 {display: none;}` within *phone_css.css* and then the MediaQuery containing `#img2 {display: none;}` in *desktop_css.css*

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much.

Comment: Just be aware that most browsers will still download both images. This is one of the main reasons why using `srcset` or `<picture>` is preferable. The answer above will technically do what you want but isn’t a best practice IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading this great series of posts on responsive images:
http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-definitions/

It does a great job describing the two main methods for doing this: `srcset` and `<picture>`.

If you care about cross-browser support, I would recommend using Picturefill:
https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check out the source for more info :)